# Why does this ActionFilterAttribute not import data to the ViewModel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, viewmodel, action-filter

I have the following attribute

```
public class ImportStatusAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var model = (IHasStatus)filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model;
        model.Status = (StatusMessageViewModel)filterContext.Controller.TempData["status"];
        filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model = model;
    }
}
```

which I test with the following test method (the first of several I'll write when this one passes...)

```
    [TestMethod]
public void OnActionExecuted_ImportsStatusFromTempDataToModel()
{
    // Arrange
    Expect(new
    {
        Status = new StatusMessageViewModel() { Subject = "The test", Predicate = "has been tested" },
        Key = "status"
    });

    var filterContext = new Mock<ActionExecutedContext>();
    var model = new Mock<IHasStatus>();
    var tempData = new TempDataDictionary();
    var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(model.Object);
    var controller = new FakeController() { ViewData = viewData, TempData = tempData };
    tempData.Add(expected.Key, expected.Status);

    filterContext.Setup(c => c.Controller).Returns(controller);
    var attribute = new ImportStatusAttribute();

    // Act
    attribute.OnActionExecuted(filterContext.Object);

    // Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(model.Object.Status, "The status was not exported");
    Assert.AreEqual(model.Object.Status.ToString(), ((StatusMessageViewModel)expected.Status).ToString(), "The status was not the expected");
}
```

(`Expect()` is a method that saves some expectations in the `expected` object...)

When I run the test, it **fails on the first assertion**, and I can't get my head around why. Debugging, I can see that `model` is populated correctly, and that `(StatusMessageViewModel)filterContext.Controller.TempData["status"]` has the correct data. But after

model.Status = (StatusMessageViewModel)filterContext.Controller.TempData["status"];

`model.Status` is still null in my watch window. Why can't I do this?

Comment: I noticed that you're using a mock IHasStatus object.  Do you perhaps have to signal to your mocking framework that you want it to treat the .Object / .Status properties as normal get/set properties rather than whatever the default behavior might be?

Comment: That was probably it - when I created a fake that implemented this interface instead, it worked as expected.

Comment: Also, it could be fixed with a call to `model.SetupProperty(c => c.Status)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Moq didn't treat the Status property correctly. A call to

```
model.SetupProperty(c => c.Status);
```

fixed the problem.